# Python Pandas add local time columns from UTC column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Panda df with a UTC column (not a timeseries index, a UTC Date field).   The data is displayed in the df as:

> 2017-11-13 05:00:00

I need to create a new column (leaving the UTC column intact), but with localtime and have it displayed as:

> 2017-11-13 00:00:00

*(assuming US/Eastern)*

I tried:

```
df['DATE_TIME_UTC'].dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
```

but this displays:

> 2017-11-13 05:00:00-5:00

and when pushed to the DB, it shows the UTC time again. Please advise how store the datetime in the new field as localtime.

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem (but in pyspark) and I just convert my date variable into a string

Comment: What @Sotos said. I had this exact same issue in BigQuery also. The db 'silently' drops the timezone offset. Easiest (but not best) way is to convert to string prior to writing to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime is currently timezone naive, only you the user know that it is in UTC.

You need to convert it to a timezone aware datetime, by using the following

```
# Create Timezone Aware using tz_localize
df['DATE_TIME_UTC'] = df['DATE_TIME_UTC'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')
```

Next you want to convert it to be the local timezone

```
# Convert to local timezone
df['DATE_TIME_LOCAL'] = df['DATE_TIME_UTC'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Now you should have the timezone information that you require.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.   This is what I was looking for.